# Getting javax.persistence.PersistenceException while persisting object using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to Stackoverflow. While am persisting my java object using JPA am getting an exception named "javax.persistence.PersistenceException".
My Java Code to persist is :

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("camel");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setAuthor("Raju");
        book.setTitle("Kiss Me");
        book.setGenre("Romance");
        em.persist(book);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
```

My Persistence.xml is :

```
<persistence-unit name="camel">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.labs.Book</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="postgres" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="raju" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Here is the stacktrace for the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "camel" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createPersistenceException(Persistence.java:244)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:186)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:72)
    at com.labs.App.main(App.java:48)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.util.GeneralException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: file:/C:/Users/omandala/EIP_Workspace/validation/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml [Location: Line: 1, C: 32]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/omandala/EIP_Workspace/validation/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 32; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence-unit'.
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parseNewResource(XMLMetaDataParser.java:427)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:347)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:324)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:297)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation$ConfigurationParser.parse(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:811)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.parseResources(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:576)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:528)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:339)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:86)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:62)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:152)
    ... 2 more
```

Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Do you have the `<persistence>` root element in your persistence.xml as well?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Yeah i missed the persistence root element. It worked.